# probability of getting two jokers out of 999 cards

Tags: probability

There are 999 Cards with two jokers.

three person(Say a,b,c) draw cards so each will have 333 cards at the end.

what is the probability for only one person getting 2 jokers at the end?

(doesn't matter if its a,b or c)

Comment: Hint: There are $\binom{997}{331}$ hands that A can have with $2$ jokers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another way:

Total number of hands that can be dealt: $\binom {999}{333} \binom {666}{333}$.
Explanation:
For first player, 333 chosen from 999 give $\binom {999}{333}$ ways
For second player, 333 chose from (999-333=) 666 cards give $\binom {666}{333}$ ways
Third player has $\binom {333}{333}$ ways.

Total = $\binom {999}{333} \binom {666}{333}$ ways of dealing the cards.

Number of hands with both jokers to one person = $\binom {997}{331} \binom {666}{333}$.

Explanation:
Let both cards go to first player, then for first player we have to choose 333-2=331 cards from 999-2=997 cards. Number of ways = $\binom{997}{331}$
For second player, 333 chose from (999-333=) 666 cards give $\binom {666}{333}$ ways
Third player has $\binom {333}{333}$ ways.

Total = $\binom {997}{331} \binom {666}{333}$ ways of dealing the cards.

Number of ways of choosing that "first" player = 3.

Explanation:
Let's say there are three players A, B and C.
Both jokers could go to A in $\binom {997}{331} \binom {666}{333}$ ways.
Similarly for B and C.

So total number of ways of dealing hands so that both jokers go to one person = 
$3\binom {997}{331} \binom {666}{333}$
Probability = $3\cdot \frac{\binom {997}{331} \binom {666}{333}}{\binom {999}{333} \binom {666}{333}}$ = $3\cdot \frac{333\cdot 332}{999\cdot 998}$ = $\frac{332}{998}$

Comment: sorry but could you explain more precisely ?

Comment: edited my answer. Check if it's clear now.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the person who gets joker $A$. The probability that this person also gets joker $B$ is approximately $\frac13$. The precise number is $\frac{332}{998}$ (good cases divided by possible cases, where a "case" is the possible occurence of joker $B$ in the drawing sequence)

Comment: sorry but could you explain more precisely?

Comment: Here is how 332/998 is derived:   the person who got joker A,   he has 332 other cards,  there is another joker among the 998 card,  the odd of that joker is among the 332 cards is 332/998.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of one person getting $2$ jokers = Probability that both other persons do not get jokers

The probability that the first person does not get a joker  = 1 - the probability that s/he gets a joker. That is clearly $1-\frac{332}{998} = \frac{666}{998}$.

Then there are two jokers left in $666$ cards. So the probability that the second person does not get a joker = 1 - the probability that s/he gets a joker. That is, like above, $1-\frac{332}{665} = \frac{333}{665}$.

Then by the multiplication rule: $\frac{666}{998} \cdot \frac{333}{665} \approx 0.33$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the current answers are complicating the problem.

The question is basically "What is probability of both jokers being with one person out of the three persons?" since total number of cards are divided equally.

I do not think the number of cards would be a matter of concern here and has been added only to add confusion.

The probability of a joker being with a person is simply 1/3.
Now both jokers are independent of each other.
Hence probability of both jokers being with one person would be (1/3)*(1/3) = 1/9 = 0.11